# Android 5.0 build errors with Java version issue

Tags: android, android-build

My current java version running on my Ubuntu 14.04 is

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

I've typed the command to change the java version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
test@test-ZX-530:/media/test/SSD/N7$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1071      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac          1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

After configuring this, the java -version does not change.

When I tried to build Android 5.0, the error occured and shown the following error message:

```
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
************************************************************
You asked for an OpenJDK 7 build but your version is
java version "1.7.0_72" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14) Java     HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode).
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:191: *** stop. Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets  ####
```

Any idea to this? Thanks!

==================================================================================

I have found out the question to this issue.

The java version is Openjdk when I run

```
. build/envsetup.sh
```

However, when I run

```
lunch aosp_flo-userdebug
```

The java version switch back to Java SE.

Please let me know if you may have any idea

Thanks

===========================================================================

Hi,

```
lunch aosp_flo-userdebug
```

I thihk this command checks my configuration and switches back to Java SE jdk version.

After running this command and exporting my OpenJDK path again make the build work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Building Kitkat needs Sun/Oracle JDK 6 version, and building Lollipop needs OpenJDK 7. Currently, I have both projects on my Ubuntu. I use a script to switch the JDK version, and it works.

Put the jdk_switch.sh in my ~ directory and run the following commands to switch jdk version:

```
$ . ./jdk_switch.sh jdk7
$ . ./jdk_switch.sh jdk6
```

The path of JDK are:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

The content of jdk_switch.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    jdk6)
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/
 ;;
    jdk7)
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
 ;;
    *)
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
 ;;
esac

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib

java -version
```

---

OpenJDK 7 version is :

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

In your case, exporting your PATH and CLASSPATH might helpful. Or just use a simple bash script. I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks. by executing your script, the script works but the error message is the same. Please let me know if you have any thoughts about this.

Comment: @Sam, Be sure to restart the terminal. New environment variables won't take effect until the terminal session is restarted.

Comment: @SagarSakre, No. It did not work in my case. I have posted the update and it works now. The root cause needs to check why lunch xxxx changes the configuration of java sdk.

Answer (score 3):

`build/core/main.mk` says:

```
# For Java 1.7, we require OpenJDK on linux and Oracle JDK on Mac OS.
requires_openjdk := false
ifeq ($(HOST_OS), linux)
requires_openjdk := true
endif
```

So Android 6 build on linux requires OpenJDK 1.7 which isn't available anymore in the Ubuntu 16.04 repo...

I've got a few solutions:

- install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS into VM (keep in mind: End of Life is 04/2019)
- enable [experimental OpenJDK 1.8 support](https://github.com/MSM8930-Samsung/android_device_samsung_expressltexx/commit/f093f45af3968dbd161e7b5260b0553a8e1a1523) in Android source
- install OpenJDK 1.7 from [ppa:openjdk/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but you need to take care about `. ./jdk_switch.sh jdk7`, you need to set environment in this terminal so you can not `./jdk_switch.sh jdk7`, after set. Double check your environment: `env|grep java`.

Answer (score 0):

only ./script indicate: run that script nothing more.

". ./script" is equal to "source ./script": every export will be in you current bash env..

Answer (score 0):

Just run 
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
before lunch command.
Its working for me